# Margin Issue With Child

Tags: html, css, animation

This issue is a little bit complicated. I am trying to position some images in the order you can in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/crvh856y/10/), but I had to add a parent div for the images so they could work properly with an animated box that displays the names of the people the images represent. The issue lies with the div not lining up the way the images do as just being lone img tags. Any help with this would be extremely appreciated.

```css
body {
 background: #7d7d7d;
}

h2 {
  font-family: Pacifico;
  font-size: 10px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  font-weight: 200;
  color: white;
  line-height: 0px;
}

#friends {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 20px;
  top: 50px;
  right: 200px;
  padding-top: 4px;
  border: 1px solid white;
 z-index: -10;
 background-color: #000;
  font-family: arial;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
}

#friends:hover {
  height: 240px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.peeps {
  position: relative;
 margin-top: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

.sam, .ys, .kani, .ash, .adam, .lit, .tsun, .lara, .bath {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.8s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.8s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.8s ease-out;
}

.sam:hover {
  border-radius: 0;
  box-shadow: 0px 0 15px #a2dfe0;
}

#name {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: -20px;
  height: 20px;
  width: 0px;
  opacity: 0;
 vertical-align: middle;
 line-height: 15px;
  background-color: #000;
  border: 1px solid white;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: -1;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

.peeps:hover #name {
  margin-top: -85px;
  height: 20px;
  width: 50px;
  opacity: 1;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #000;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <div id="friends">
    <br><br><!-- jsfiddle doesn't like my text -->
    <div class="peeps">
      <img class="sam" src="http://usd.chatango.com/profileimg/s/a/samantha/thumb.jpg" />
      <p id="name" style="text-align: center;">
        <font color="white" size="1">Ugh</font>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="peeps">
      <img class="ys" src="http://usd.chatango.com/profileimg/y/s/ys/thumb.jpg">
      <p id="name" style="text-align: center;">
        <font color="white" size="1">Ugh</font>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="peeps">
      <img class="kani" src="http://usd.chatango.com/profileimg/k/a/kaninkiller/thumb.jpg">
      <p id="name" style="text-align: center;">
        <font color="white" size="1">Ugh</font>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</html>
```

Comment: *The issue lies with the div not lining up the way the images do as just being lone img tags.* Huh??

Comment: @connexo you should undo your edit; the fiddle was an example, the snippet a different attempt.

Comment: Still don't get what OP wants to achieve. Nonetheless, note that `<font>` has for decades been deprecated from the web standards. Don't use that dreaded tag.

Comment: Completely agree

Comment: I want the images to line up horizontally next to eachother like it shows in the first fiddle. But doing it with the divs doesn't wield the same results sadly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly just set the `.peeps` class to `display:inline-block;`.  Here is a snippet.

```css
body {
 background: #7d7d7d;
}

h2 {
  font-family: Pacifico;
  font-size: 10px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  font-weight: 200;
  color: white;
  line-height: 0px;
}

#friends {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 20px;
  top: 50px;
  right: 200px;
  padding-top: 4px;
  border: 1px solid white;
 z-index: -10;
 background-color: #000;
  font-family: arial;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
}

#friends:hover {
  height: 240px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.peeps {
  position: relative;
 margin-top: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display:inline-block;
}

.sam, .ys, .kani, .ash, .adam, .lit, .tsun, .lara, .bath {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.8s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.8s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.8s ease-out;
}

.sam:hover {
  border-radius: 0;
  box-shadow: 0px 0 15px #a2dfe0;
}

#name {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: -20px;
  height: 20px;
  width: 0px;
  opacity: 0;
 vertical-align: middle;
 line-height: 15px;
  background-color: #000;
  border: 1px solid white;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: -1;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

.peeps:hover #name {
  margin-top: -85px;
  height: 20px;
  width: 50px;
  opacity: 1;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #000;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}
```

```html
    <div id="friends">
      <br><br> <!-- jsfiddle doesn't like my text -->

      <img class="sam" src="http://usd.chatango.com/profileimg/s/a/samantha/thumb.jpg">

      <img class="ys" src="http://usd.chatango.com/profileimg/y/s/ys/thumb.jpg">

      <img class="kani" src="http://usd.chatango.com/profileimg/k/a/kaninkiller/thumb.jpg">

      <img class="ash" src="http://usd.chatango.com/profileimg/m/u/multiplelovearrows/thumb.jpg">

      <img class="adam" src="http://usd.chatango.com/profileimg/t/i/tiefier/thumb.jpg">

      <img class="lit" src="http://usd.chatango.com/profileimg/l/i/littered/thumb.jpg">

      <img class="tsun" src="http://usd.chatango.com/profileimg/n/i/nicholle/thumb.jpg">

      <img class="lara" src="http://usd.chatango.com/profileimg/h/o/hopefulhero/thumb.jpg">

   <img class="bath" src="http://usd.chatango.com/profileimg/m/a/maytimes/thumb.jpg">
    </div>
```